# how to get the directory of a process using autohotkey?

Tags: process, autohotkey

I want to find out the directory of a process.
Currently, I am using this script to check if a process is running:

```
If ProcessExist("MEmuHeadless.exe")
    MsgBox MEmuHeadless.exe exists.

If !ProcessExist("MEmuHeadless.exe")
    MsgBox Ofcourse it doesn't exist.

ProcessExist(Name){
    Process,Exist,%Name%
    return Errorlevel
}
```

but more than that, I want to check if the directory of the process matches this:

[image]

how can I do that in autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for you. It appears you have to search through some com objects to get the extra information on the process.

```
Msgbox % GetProcessPath( "Autohotkey.exe" )
ExitApp
GetProcessPath(exe) {
    for process in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where name ='" exe "'")
        return process.ExecutablePath
}
```